# Логирование в Python (не создаётся файл с текущей датой)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!
Есть простой код, который логирует данные с помощью стандартного logging.
Проблема: насколько я понимаю, logging.basicConfig() вызывается один раз. Поэтому имя файла у меня создаётся также единожды и не меняется на следующий день. Т.е. запустил скрипт 17 февраля, получил файл логов вида 17_02_2022.log, скрипт работает и на следующий день, но файл 18_02_2022.log - не создаётся, а все данные сохраняются во "вчерашний" файл.
Альтернативы, которые вижу: логировать данные через print(file=), посмотреть в сторону loguru.
Есть ли возможность работать через logging, но с созданием нового файла ежедневно?

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import logging


while True:
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=f"./Logs/{datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y')}.log",
        format='%(asctime)s: (%(filename)s: %(lineno)d), %(funcName)s -- %(levelname)s -- %(name)s: "%(message)s"',
        level=logging.DEBUG
    )

    logging.info('Some message')
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/11/python-how-to-create-rotating-logs/

Answer (score 0):

Да но с костылями вида

```
l = logging.Logger(...
filename=...
while 1:
    if filename!={datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y')}:
          #создаём новый логер
          l=logging.Logger....
```